# CKEditor 5 custom image upload does upload the file but editor says it was not

Tags: php, json, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Edit: realised I had not made it clear that I had added the simple upload adapter plugin to my build and enabled it as instructed.

I have followed the guidance for setting up an image upload handler for CKE5 and have adapted my CKE4 upload handler (PHP page) to handle the actual file upload.  It works in that the file arrives as intended but CKEditor just says "Couldn't upload file:".

I assume I am returning the wrong data to CKE from the PHP page.  This is how it is returned (I think the variable names should let you know what is inside):

```
if(isset($messageToUser)){
    $returnedObject->error->message = $messageToUser;   
} else {
    $returnedObject->url = $uploadedURL;
}    

$returnedJSON=json_encode($returnedObject, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo $returnedJSON;
```

and if I also write the returned object to a text file I see the correct URL:

> {"url":"./learningresources/group151/project1613/Untitled-1.png"}

I know nothing about JSON so would appreciate some advice.

Edit 2:  N.B. I have also tried using an absolute URL

Answer (score 0):

OK thankfully I can now answer my own question.  The problem is with the second and fourth lines of code above.  Although they are correct they throw a warning because I am implicitly creating an object.  Not being OO myself that only just occurred to me.  I have all warnings showing during development so it was pre-empting the sending of the headers and blocking their sending.  I fixed it by creating the object beforehand with:

```
$returnedObject = new \stdClass();
```